# I can't manage to communicate across Activities using intents

Tags: android, kotlin

In my MainActivity onCreate I have a button listener which switches to a second activity:

```
    editorLink.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, EditorActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

In my second activity I have another button listener which attempts to switch back to the first activity, passing it some new data:

```
    saveButton.setOnClickListener {
        val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
        intent.putExtra("my_data", "my data from other activity");
        startActivity(intent)
    }
```

Then in my MainActivity onStart I attempt to read the extra data:

```
if (intent.extras != null) {
   myData =  intent.extras!!.getString("my_data")
}
```

However the intent.extras is always null here.

I have put Logger calls everywhere and I am sure all the above code is being run and the data being added to extras is a valid string.

Comment: Have you tried setResult and onActivityResult?

Comment: @SahityaPasnoor the duplicate question has the correct answer, I needed to use `onNewIntent` instead of `onStart`